# ¿Cómo se dice "forehand" en un juego de cartas?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, juegos

Estoy traduciendo las reglas del juego de cartas (de bazas) alemán "Tarock" y hay un término que usan en alemán y en inglés cuya traducción al español no logro encontrar (y de hecho tampoco sé como se dice en francés, mi primer idioma). El "forehand" es el jugador sentado al lado del que distribuyó las cartas, y que abre el juego en la primera ronda, poniendo la primera carta en la mesa. ¿Existe alguna traducción?

En el Tarock, a veces empieza el "forehand" y a veces la persona que hizo la apuesta más alta (el licitador). Estoy buscando una palabra para referirme al primer caso sin ambigüedad con el segundo.

Comment: You may well be right but I know that as eldest hand in English (or elder in a two-player game). Perhaps that might help to track it down?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El jugador que empieza primero en un juego de cartas es la **mano**:

> **mano**
>
> 36. m. y f. En ciertos juegos, persona a quien en cada momento le corresponde jugar en primer lugar. *Yo soy mano.*

Dado que ya estáis usando otra palabra para el jugador que abre por hacer la apuesta más alta (el "licitador"), podéis usar "mano" para referiros siempre al que abre por posición, es decir por sentarse al lado de quien reparte.

Comment: Aunque esa parte no lo dice el DLE en muchos juegos de cartas *mano* es el que esta a la derecha del que reparte y empieza el juego por norma general. De hecho yo diría que es mano por su posición y no porque empiece el juego.

Comment: Ni idea de poker, en el mus por ejemplo es el de la derecha pero lo mismo da, está al lado del que reparte, a una mano o a la otra.